# invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'int' in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm pretty new to C, and I've been using an [online C compiler](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/) for most of my projects. The compiler has been giving me the following message:

> dc0dtnYW.c: In function 'int main(int, char**)': 
>   dc0dtnYW.c:48: error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'int'

referring to the second line in the below piece:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{   int load (argv);
    return 0;}
```

My int load function looks like this:

```
int load (char* filename) {
```

I haven't found any other instances of this problem online. Why is the compiler saying that I'm trying to convert a char** to an int?

Answer (score 1):

The line `int load(argv)` doesn't call the `load` function. Rather, it creates an integer variable called `load`, and initializes it from `argv` (which doesn't work, because it's not an integer).

You probably want to do `load(argv[1])`.

Comment: Since `load` returns an `int`, he probably wants something like `int something = load(argv[1]);`.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is an array of pointers to chars. You are trying to convert it to a pointer to chars. `argv` is an array of command line arguments not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you al ready declare a function `int load (char* filename)`  you don't need to use again `int` when you call that function. More than that you have to pass `argv[1]` to the function instead `argv`. If you do so `Argv[1]` will pass first parameter of your process to function `load`

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{  
    load (argv[1]); // You dont need int in this line 
    return 0;

}
```